# .Net Assembly appears to disappear during runtime using Razor and NopCommerce 2.65

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

In my project I've added some custom code to the CategoryNavigation, just a call to a stored database procedure via IDbContext.

My NopCommerce site now crashes after between 10 to 30 minutes of runtime with a "Could not load type" error, which occurs from a Razor Layout file.

Clearly my class (which is compiled into Nop.Web assembly) cannot have disappeared during runtime. On altering the Razor script during the fault, I have found that other Actions and Views work, as do other classes.

The fault does not go away until an edit to Global.asax, an App Pool recycle, or recompile - the former two methods of regaining a proper state would tend to suggest that no files went walkabout.

Is there any generally known mechanism in DotNet where a fault in a program can cause it's class type to become unavailable to the rest of the program? Is anyone aware of a mechanism in NopCommerce that would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out what the problem is with our NopCommerce 2.65

In short, our plugins were outputting all of their references into their Plugin folder, and the Plugin Manager was loading them all.

In effect, because we had registered Nop.Web, and then continued to customise the real Nop.Web, the version in our plugin folder ran out of kilter and lacked any of our customisations.

It appears that Razor prefers to use the version loaded by the plugin manager, and this explains all of the problems that we had. Our solution is now stable and quick.

Hope this helps someone with a similar problem.

Kind Regards,
Mark Rabjohn
[Integrated Arts Ltd](http://www.ia.uk.com)